# Where to place the code for best practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

I have an asp.net mvc application and I have a page for presenting meteo information. It looks like:

> Temperature for today is 34-35 degrees

For this

> 34-35 degrees

, I have a method that assure that the text will be in format

> [Number][Dot][Number]

called AssureCorrectDegressFormat().
Now I am asking where is it suited the best. Untill now I was calling it from the view, smth like this:

> 

But as I think the view is intended only to display data , not to call some methods in order to operate with thise literals. I moved my class SafeData to the Core of my application, and I pass to the view the DTO that has already called this method and obtained the right data for displaying. I am interested in your opinions about this, where is the best place to put this class, maybe in Infrastructure layer and where to call it, now I call itr from my services . I forgot to say that I am using a DDD aproach.

Comment: I hate any programming functions with grammar articles like 'The' in. Can it not be something like ToDegreeString()?!

Comment: DV = ViewData.Model, so TheDegreeString - is a property not a method here : DV.TheDegreeString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formatting, from my perspective, is a view-related function and so it should be called in the view.  As to the code that actually does the formatting, I might create an HtmlHelper extension to handle the formatting.  That way I could use it wherever I wanted, but have the code in only one place.

```
 <%= Html.ShowDegrees( DV.TheDegreeString ) %>
```

Comment: HtmlHelpers have the added benefit of reducing angst among developers when it comes to formatting methods appearing in the View.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting the display of data in the View seems fine to me.  You wouldn't think twice about about putting this on your View:

```
<%= Model.MyDate.ToString("f") %>
```

would you?  The principal is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a very simple formatting or calculation, I just put it in the view.  If it's any more complex than that, I will put a method in the ViewModel.  If it is complex and can be used many places, I will create an HtmlHelper for it.